# Send html email with java using html external template?

Tags: java, html, email, aem

I'm trying to send an HTML email with parameters and attachments.
What i have right now is this code:

```
<%@include file="/libs/fd/af/components/guidesglobal.jsp" %>
<%@page import="com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.FormsHelper,
                org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceUtil,
                org.apache.sling.api.resource.ValueMap,
                org.apache.sling.api.request.RequestParameter,
                com.day.cq.mailer.MessageGatewayService,
                com.day.cq.mailer.MessageGateway,
                org.apache.commons.mail.Email,
                org.apache.fulcrum.template.TemplateHtmlEmail,
                org.apache.commons.mail.*" %>
<%@taglib prefix="sling" uri="http://sling.apache.org/taglibs/sling/1.0" %>
<%@taglib prefix="cq" uri="http://www.day.com/taglibs/cq/1.0"
%>
<cq:defineObjects/>
<sling:defineObjects/>
<%
    String storeContent = "/libs/fd/af/components/guidesubmittype/store";
    FormsHelper.runAction(storeContent, "post", resource, slingRequest, slingResponse);
    ValueMap props = ResourceUtil.getValueMap(resource);
    HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();
    String[] mailTo = props.get("mailto", new String[0]);
    email.setFrom((String)props.get("from"));
        for (String toAddr : mailTo) {
            email.addTo(toAddr);
      }

    String htmlEmailTemplate = props.get("templatePath");

    //========Email Attachments===============
    for (Map.Entry<String, RequestParameter[]> param : slingRequest.getRequestParameterMap().entrySet()) {
        RequestParameter rpm = param.getValue()[0];
        if(!rpm.isFormField()) {
            EmailAttachment attachment = new EmailAttachment();
            attachment.setPath(rpm.getFileName());
            attachment.setDisposition(EmailAttachment.ATTACHMENT);
            attachment.setDescription("Any Description");
            attachment.setName("Any name you can set");
            email.embed(new ByteArrayDataSource(rpm.get(), rpm.getContentType()), rpm.getFileName());
        }
    }
    //========Email Attachment END===========

    String emailTextToSend = "<p>Company Name: " + slingRequest.getParameter("company-name") + "</p>";
    emailTextToSend += "<p>Message: " + slingRequest.getParameter("address") + "</p>";
    email.setHtmlMsg(emailTextToSend);
    email.setSubject((String)props.get("subject"));
    MessageGatewayService messageGatewayService = sling.getService(MessageGatewayService.class);
    MessageGateway messageGateway = messageGatewayService.getGateway(HtmlEmail.class);
    messageGateway.send(email);
%>
```

With this code i can send the email, but i want to modify the code to use a path to an html template file (the path is on the variable `htmlEmailTemplate`.

This is my first question, how to change that code.
My second question is that if in that template i can have something like this:

```
<span>${company-name}</span>
```

Where `company-name` is one of the fields that i want to use on the template.
Is this possible?

Comment: Check templating engines like velocity

Comment: My intention is not to use a templating engine and just use HtmlEmail

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the com.day.cq.commons.mail.MailTemplate api 
if your template is in the JCR repository, you can instantiate it with something like:

```
String template = values.get(TEMPLATE_PROPERTY, String.class);
Resource templateRsrc = request.getResourceResolver().getResource(template);
final MailTemplate mailTemplate = MailTemplate.create(templateRsrc.getPath(),
           templateRsrc.getResourceResolver().adaptTo(Session.class));
final HtmlEmail email = mailTemplate.getEmail(StrLookup.mapLookup(properties), HtmlEmail.class);
```

Where properties is simply a HashMap of Key:Values for the template's own properties.

Since the MailTemplate returns a HtmlEmail object, you can still set all the settings you set in your own code as well.